# Cannot find workspace?

Tags: ros, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried writing the simple publisher and subscriber using the tutorial, but seem to have some problem finding the workspace and packages using ros...
I've source it like a million times.. and I still can't find it...

what am I doing wrong??
Workspace uploaded here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ip6qm3lc40v93nz/pubsub_ws.zip?dl=0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203205/cannot-find-workspace??/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) on 2015-02-16**:
Can you cd to the directory of your ros-project (which is located in path/catkin_ws/src/) and try and launch the file from within it. If not to go to the location of the launch file of your project and do:$ roslaunch project.launch

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-02-16**:
To confirm that your workspace is successfully sourced you can run just "roscd". you should end up in the workspace/devel folder.
To update the list of packages you need to run "rospack profile"
Please refer to [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/202239/rosed-cmakelisttxt/) for more detail

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-18**:
I am able to cd it, but there is no launch file.
Roscd doesn't show the ws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I downloaded your workspace. It seems that some things haven't been initialized properly. If I source it and type roscd I end up in pubsub_ws/devel. But I cannot roscd the packages.
Can you run the following ?
cd ~/pubsub_ws
rm -rf build/ devel/ install/ src/CMakeLists.txt
cd src catkin_init_workspace
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
rospack profile
roscd commands

Explaination : When I ran rospack profile I never saw yiur workspace showing in the list. So your packages were never in the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.
To fix it you need to reinitialize your workspace. then rebuild it and update your package list (the list of commands above).Then everything should be working.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-18**:
I keep getting these error when i create a new workspace I can't see what I am doing wrong..
Usually when i create a workspace i do this..

http://pastebin.com/2dPnwmhv

I then add my .cpp files in src directory and run catkin_make and then should rosrun be able run.. which is not the case..

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-02-18**:
you still cannot roscd your workspace ?
can you post the output of all the commands above ?
and output of pwd after running "roscd" alone ?

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-19**:
no errors occurs... why can't i run rosrun....

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-02-19**:
If you don't give more info we can't help you... What do you mean by no error ?
can you post the output of all the commands above ? and output of pwd after running "roscd" alone ?

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-19**:
roscd cannot find it

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-02-19**:
Can you paste the output of:
"rospack profile"
"echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"
and "roscd" ?
Please